# Set folder in uiputfile - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I make the uiputfile open the PathFile folder? It is done in App designer

Code:

```
pathFile = 'E:/';   
filter = {'*.txt'};
[file, pathFile] = uiputfile(filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
pathFile = 'E:/';   
filter = {'*.txt'};
[file, pathFile] = uiputfile([pathFile,filter{1}])
```